# Multiple terminals don't always restore

Tags: gnome-terminal

I generally keep half a dozen terminal windows open. On reboot, usually they are restored to their previous size and position, even if I have closed them all before rebooting.

However, sometimes they don't restore but are all on top of each other in the upper left of the screen. Is this a bug, or is there a setting somewhere that can guarantee that they will be restored as desired?

I have tried adding "gnome-terminal --load-config=my_saved_config" to my profile, but this just doubles up the number of terminals, so apparently the configuration is already being saved somewhere else.

Where is all this controlled? I have searched the forums and the likely places in the file system, but have not found anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you organised your terminals on screen (as in the screenshot below), and then from one of the four you ran `gnome-terminal --save-config=Mik4`, the resulting file will be saved to the present working directory (pwd) of that terminal (or the script running that command).

However, if the present working directory (pwd) in which you saved the config was anything other than `/home/$USER`, running `gnome-terminal --load-config=Mik4` will not work, as it only looks in `/home/$USER`. You need to specify the exact location where you saved it and run, for example, `gnome-terminal --load-config=~/DOS/Mik3`. Then you can could add your command  as a custom shortcut or you could even replace the standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

It does restore my configuration perfectly for me every time, and seems to be fine as long as you select the correct config file; it is best to keep your configs in `/home/$USER`, then you can save and load without needing to remember to specify any other directory.

Entering `man gnome-terminal` doesn't give the full options, but `gnome-terminal --help-all` should provide any further information that you need.

[image]